# MultiIndex for pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have this code:

```
 new_dict = {'x':[1,2,3,4,5], 'y':[11,22,33,44,55], 'val':[100, 200, 300, 400, 500]}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(new_dict)   
    val  x   y
0  100  1  11
1  200  2  22
2  300  3  33
3  400  4  44
4  500  5  55
```

I want to be able to use values of `x` and `y` in combination as index into `val`,
for example

```
df[3][33]
300
```

What's the best way to achieve this? I know it must have to do with multi index, but I am not sure exactly how.

Comment: Sorry are you asking for `df.loc[(df['x']==3) & (df['y']==33), 'val']`?

Comment: That will indeed give the correct result, but I was wondering if there is more elegant, syntax-wise cleaner approach.

Comment: Well you don't have a multi-index here and besides what you're looking for are row value matches you're not using any index here

Comment: Thanks. But is it more practical to construct a multi-index, and then use that?

Comment: It depends but if you did set the index then you can do `df.set_index(['x','y']).loc[3,33]` which syntactically maybe easier for you

Comment: And also you can define function for that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either define 2 boolean conditions as a mask and use with `.loc`:

```
df.loc[(df['x']==3) & (df['y']==33), 'val']
```

otherwise just set the index and then you can use those values to index into the df:

```
In [233]:
df = df.set_index(['x','y'])
df.loc[3,33]

Out[233]:
val    300
Name: (3, 33), dtype: int64
```

You could wrap the first version into a func quite easily

Answer (score 1):

You can define a function :

```
new_dict = {'x':[1,2,3,4,5], 'y':[11,22,33,44,55], 'val':[100, 200, 300, 400,   500]}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(new_dict) 

def multindex(x,y):
    return df.set_index(['x','y']).loc[x,y]

multindex(1,11) #will return '100'
```

Comment: This seems pretty wasteful to construct a df with a multi-index for the purpose of returning a single element